# modular application (g-brief & moderncv) without changing \documentclass?

Tags: moderncv, external-files

im writing a job application, so id like to have just one pdf document, which would contain my cover letter and my moderncv resumee.

Both parts are working for themself, but i when i `\input` my resumee, nothing changes. I think because of the additional `\usepackage` and `\documentclass` and that stuff. 
The ideal solution would be one that allows me to use both documents, without changing their `\documentclass` and such.

What would the best way to achieve such modular document?

**EDIT**: the potential solution with `\includepdf` also doesnt work, although erika.pdf is in the same folder. When i move `\includepdf[pages=1]{./erika.pdf}` to line above the `\begin{document}`, i receive an "Undefined control sequence" error at the `\includepdf` line

```
<!-- language: lang-latex -->
\documentclass[12pt,german]{g-brief}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{times}


\fenstermarken \trennlinien

\Name {Maxi Muster}
\Strasse {Musterstra\ss{}e 20}
\Unterschrift {Maxi Muster}

\Adresse { Muster GmbH \& Co. KG\\- Personalabteilung -\\
                     Landstra\ss{}e 2\\12345 Musterstadt}

\Betreff {Bewerbung als ...} \Datum {\today}
\Anrede {Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\Gruss {Mit freundlichen Gr\"{u}\ss{}en}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{g-brief}
test
\end{g-brief}
\end{document}
\includepdf[pages=1]{./erika.pdf}






%coverletter    
\documentclass[12pt,german]{g-brief}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{times}


\fenstermarken \trennlinien

\Name {Maxi Muster}
\Strasse {Musterstra\ss{}e 20}
\Unterschrift {Maxi Muster}

\Adresse { Muster GmbH \& Co. KG\\- Personalabteilung -\\
             Landstra\ss{}e 2\\12345 Musterstadt}

\Betreff {Bewerbung als ...} \Datum {\today}
\Anrede {Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\Gruss {Mit freundlichen Gr\"{u}\ss{}en}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{g-brief}

\end{g-brief}
\end{document}

\input{./erika}






%resumee
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[red]{casual} %[blue, green, orange, red, grey]{casual, classic}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\firstname{Erika}
\familyname{Mustermann}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Persönliche Angaben}
\cventry{Geburt}{12. August 1964}{Berlin}{}{}{}
\cventry{Familienstand}{verheiratet, 2 Kinder}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{Ehemann}{Max Mustermann}{Musterberuf}{}{}{}

%\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{}

\section{Ausbildung}
\subsection{Schule}


Musterstadt, \today
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\includepdf[pages=1]{./erika.pdf}` has to be between `\end{g-brief}`
and `\end{document}`. Works fine :)